# Strange effects when using a long axis in TChart

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, teechart

I have put a tchart on a delphi form (XE4) and make the width 65535 pixels (the maximum). I have set the scale of the bottom axis to fixed values (minimum 0, maximum 65534) and then I add values using something like:

```
  for i := 0 to 60000 do
chart1.series[0].addXY(i, 10 + (i mod 80));
```

The result is some strange behaviour with additional lines being plotted on locations where they shouldn't be, while any point beyond 32767 is missing. The same thing happens when setting the maximum of the bottom axis to for example 5000 and fill the whole thing with 'only' 100 samples between 0 and 5000. Remarkable is the fact that some combinations of adding values close to the maximum value of the bottom axis do seem to work (even beyond 32767 pixels from the left).

Does anyone has some insight into the reasons of this behaviour? Is there any way to solve this problem aside from not using tcharts with a width over 32767 pixels?

Comment: Are you really using 65K-pixel wide chart? Is it possible to make a window with such size?

Comment: I put the chart inside a TScrollbox, which works fine

Comment: What type of chart are you using?  FastLine, etc?  Sounds like a `DrawAllPoints` issue - try setting it to `True`.  Also experiment with the different `DrawAllPointsStyle`s.

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way. I would do it like this. Put a chart and two scrollbars inside a panel. Scroll bars with `alRight` and `alBottom` alignment, chart with `alClient`. When the user scrolls, change the data shown on the chart. If you want to put all the data in up front, then use the scroll bars to modify the axis ranges. Or you could just re-populate the data on demand if there's a lot of it. Of course, I'm fairly sure the chart will have scrolling functionality.

Comment: Agreed that this is not a sensible solution to any real-world problem.  TChart has a lot of optimizations that you are likely short-circuiting with such a ridiculously non-physical chart size.  Put the chart on (ie: *within*) the screen and let the chart do the work like @DavidHeffernan suggests.

Comment: @J: I'm using the TChart which is packed with Delphi, so I cannot use the FastLineSeries. I assume DrawAllPoints is a property of TFastLineSeries? I don't think this will solve the problem, as I have the same problem even with just a few points (if they are far enough to the right side of the chart)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Unfortunately, I need to use a background image for the chart, which can have such a rediculous width. Furthermore, I have many thousands of points and constantly having to remove all plotted points and going though all data and selecting which to add takes too much time to allow for smooth scrolling.

Comment: You can certainly do it the way I say. It is absolutely possible. However, if you prefer to do it your way then that's up to you.

Answer (score 3):

`TFastLineSeries` is not available in TeeChart Lite for FMX, but it is in TeeChart Standard for VCL.
See the feature matrix [here](http://www.steema.com/featurematrix/vcl).

I've been able to reproduce the problem in a VCL project using a `TLineSeries`, so I've added it to the public [tracker](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=737). In the meanwhile, if you are in VCL you can change to a `TFastLineSeries`.

Comment: It is good to know TFastLineSeries works fine, however, it is not visible in my version of Delphi (see http://www.teechart.net/support//viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14145&sid=eab764223d9a8a19bec9719a32dde1bf). Moreover, I have the same problems with TPointSeries

Comment: I have installed the patch, which enabled TFastLineSeries which I have been using successfully.